# How do I create a file from the localStorage and send it to my RestEndpoint?

Tags: ionic-framework

I have some data saved on my `Localstorage` under the `index` **`file.txt`**.
I'm currently writing an `RestEndpoint` function call which takes a `param` of `textfile`.

How am I going to write an `restendpoint` function call and pass my data from `localstorage` as `params`?

Comment: Am I asking a bad question? Already a negative :(. I need help!

Comment: 1. create a file 2. write text from localstorage to file. 3. post text file to API.

Comment: @HardikVaghani How do I do that? Create a file? I already have a data in my localstorage under the index of 'file.txt' (I'm not sure if that is a file, it's just a name and data in it).

Comment: Use http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/ to create file and write your local storage data to it. __AND__ With https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/01/upload-files-remote-server-using-ionic-framework/ link you will be able to  post that file to remote server.

Comment: @HardikVaghani I ahve been using $fileLogger plugin. Does this plugin create the file and store it in LocalStorage? Or it just store object data?

Comment: The plugin i suggested will create file in local file system and also writes to file.